# Find most recent stock quotes for a specific date

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-query-language

I have a table in Google spreadsheet like this:

```
Stock                    Date          Price
```

```
DNB Nordic Technology    2016-07-12    968,7449
DNB Nordic Technology    2016-07-13    970,0482
DNB Nordic Technology    2016-07-14    970,0500
Elementa                 2016-03-30   1167,0704
Elementa                 2016-04-30   1175,8091
Elementa                 2016-05-31   1184,1240
Elementa                 2016-06-30   1196,5268
Evli Emerging Frontier B 2016-07-12   1164,6900
Evli Emerging Frontier B 2016-07-14   1171,3400
```

What I need is a table with only the most recent price for each stock for a specific date ex 2016-07-13

```
DNB Nordic Technology       2016-07-13  970,0500
Elementa                    2016-06-30 1196,5268
Evli Emerging Frontier B    2016-07-12 1166,9200
```

I want to use a query so I can use the result/table and run a single query using ARRAYFORMULA(sum... (quantity * price)) to get total value for my portfolio.

pls help :)

This query will result in latest date but no prices :(

QUERY('stock'!$A:$C;"select A, max(B) where A<>'' group by A label A '', max(B) ''")

Comment: Are you pulling in the data dynamically or is it a static table?

Comment: Hi, this query is for calculate historical values so the table is semi static (I update it once a weak). But i need a query to calculate value for many dates and several portfolios so i still need a query. This is for calculate NAV for each portfolio.

Comment: Can you. Share a sheet?

Comment: Sure, here is a sheet. Query in F2 will result in a table with name and last date, but not the price
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FH0_w7ZNAZIQ41AQZz4ylxJETfUgDCAjEth9skZxThc/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISTEXT(UNIQUE(A2:A)),VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(A2:A),SORT(A2:C,1,true,2,false),{1,2,3},false),))
```

What I did here was first give it a condition to only run on the rows that have a potential value, so it doesnt stall the sheet - then I sort, first by name (ascending), then by date (descending) so that we only need the first row of each name, date pair, then I return all the indexes

[image]

Here is the updated format for your locale:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISTEXT(UNIQUE(A2:A));VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(A2:A);SORT(A2:C;1;true;2;false);{1\2\3};false);))
```

IF YOU NEED THE DATE PARAMATER ALSO HERE IS THAT MODIFICATION:

```
 =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISTEXT(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A;B:B<=D1)));VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A;B:B<=D1));SORT(FILTER(A:C;B:B<=D1);1;true;2;false);{1\2\3};false);))
```

All I did was add a filter function over the array - also note this formula doesnt need to use query at all

[image]

Comment: I getting an error, not sure why. And I'm also so sry to say that I forgot one criteria, pls se comments on answer below.

Comment: The error is because I didn't know your locale uses semicolon, if you convert all my commas to semicolons it should work

Comment: I added the proper format for you locale at the bottom there

Comment: and also added the filter addition to solve your second requirement you mentioned below @Per-ÅkeFranklind

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(unique(A2:A); sort(A2:C; 2; 0); {1\2\3} ;0)))
```

Comment: It works perfekt, but i'm so sry, I forgot one criteria. I need to know the latest price for a specific date. In the spreadsheet I have added Date in E2 and J2. Is it possible to add a criteria on your solution in a similar way I did in my query (F2)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FH0_w7ZNAZIQ41AQZz4ylxJETfUgDCAjEth9skZxThc/edit#gid=0